# SSRS Report: sending to a single user on demand?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am writing an MVC application for a group that already uses SSRS for reports and data-driven subscription notifications.  I would like to piggy-back off their "reports" for notifications (your request has been approved, etc).  Is it possible to utilize SSRS programatically to generate a canned report as an email to a single user on demand?  Is this done through the SSRS web service API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30599732/587817

Comment: Will you be needing to use any parameters from the report subscription or just monitor a database to send the subscription? You can trigger subscriptions from SSRS.. setup a required subscription and find out what the jobname is (GUID) and then trigger it using sp_start_job against msdb